# missing cases in switch of type parsing.tokenType on golinter

Tags: go, glide-golang, golint, golangci-lint

So I have this code

```
token := NextToken()
switch token.Typ {
case tokenEOF:
    return nil
case tokenMentionTargetedControl:
    # do stuff
default:
    return nil
}
```

my tokentype is a enum

my golinter is throwing this error:

```
missing cases in switch of type parsing.tokenType: parsing.tokenControl, parsing.tokenLinkControl, parsing.tokenMailtoControl, parsing.tokenMentionControl, parsing.tokenChannelControl, parsing.tokenText (exhaustive)
```

I don't want to create a case for each scenario, since I have the default clause, how to I avoid this?

Comment: Disable this linter or this check. Or have a case with all that `Typ`s the linter complains and a default that panics.

Comment: I would like to avoid disabling this linter, he is there for a reason, for now, I have a case with all the linter complaints, but seems like a poor solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exhaustive` linter has the `default-signifies-exhaustive` option. Set it to `true`:

```yaml
linters:
  enable:
    - exhaustive
linters-settings:
  exhaustive:
    # Presence of "default" case in switch statements satisfies exhaustiveness,
    # even if all enum members are not listed.
    # Default: false
    default-signifies-exhaustive: true
```

See https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/#exhaustive.